# How to delete terms having non-existing array elements?

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider two arrays (`ar1`, `ar2`) as

```
ar1 = RandomInteger[5,4];
ar2 = RandomInteger[5,3];
```

Now I have a set of equations as follows:

```
ar3[[1]] = 2*(ar1[[0]]*ar2[[1]]+ar1[[1]]*ar2[[2]]+ar1[[2]]*ar2[[3]]);
ar3[[2]] = 3*(ar1[[1]]*ar2[[1]]+ar1[[2]]*ar2[[2]]+ar1[[3]]*ar2[[3]]);
ar3[[3]] = 3*(ar1[[2]]*ar2[[1]]+ar1[[3]]*ar2[[2]]+ar1[[4]]*ar2[[3]]);
ar3[[4]] = 2*(ar1[[3]]*ar2[[1]]+ar1[[4]]*ar2[[2]]+ar1[[5]]*ar2[[3]]);
```

Clearly, `ar1[[0]]` is the `List` which is not desired and for `ar1[[5]]` the index is out of bounds and the numbers at the beginning of the `rhs` indicate the numbers of valid terms summed up. In this smaller set, it is possible to manually discard the terms (e.g. `ar1[[0]]*ar2[[1]]`) corresponding to such elements. How can I do it programmatically for a much larger set?

**Edit 1:** Following the answers, I think one constraint is overlooked and that is the first number on the `rhs`. This indicates the number of valid expressions to be summed up. These numbers are input manually even in the answers. However, I want the number to be computed programmatically.

Comment: `ListConvolve[ar2, ar1, {2, -2}, 0]` will produce the outputs you want without  the prefactors. You can add the prefactors by hand afterward since it is a vector whose length is the same as `ar1`, with values that are the length of `ar2`, except that the endpoints are decremented.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, your `ar3` needs to be defined too and I strongly advise that you tackle this problem earlier in your chain when you created those invalid `Part` expressions. Anyway, you can hold your expression so that it does not evaluate and replace all invalid array accesses like this:

```
ar1 = RandomInteger[5, 4];
ar2 = RandomInteger[5, 3];
ar3 = ConstantArray[0, 4];

Hold[
  ar3[[1]] = 2*(ar1[[0]]*ar2[[1]] + ar1[[1]]*ar2[[2]] + ar1[[2]]*ar2[[3]]); 
  ar3[[2]] = 3*(ar1[[1]]*ar2[[1]] + ar1[[2]]*ar2[[2]] + ar1[[3]]*ar2[[3]]); 
  ar3[[3]] = 3*(ar1[[2]]*ar2[[1]] + ar1[[3]]*ar2[[2]] + ar1[[4]]*ar2[[3]]); 
  ar3[[4]] = 2*(ar1[[3]]*ar2[[1]] + ar1[[4]]*ar2[[2]] + ar1[[5]]*ar2[[3]]);
  ] /. HoldPattern[l_[[i_]]] :> 0 /; i < 1 || i > Length[l]
```

If this is OK, you can evaluate it by using `ReleaseHold[%]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this “hack”:

```
NullifyMissing[expr_] := 
    Hold[expr] /. HoldPattern[ar_[[n_]]] :> 0 /; n <= 0 || n > Length[ar] // ReleaseHold
SetAttributes[NullifyMissing, HoldFirst]
```

It replaces all the missing elements with 0:

```
ar3 = Table[0, {4}];
ar3[[1]] = 2*(ar1[[0]]*ar2[[1]] + ar1[[1]]*ar2[[2]] + ar1[[2]]*ar2[[3]]) // NullifyMissing;
ar3[[2]] = 3*(ar1[[1]]*ar2[[1]] + ar1[[2]]*ar2[[2]] + ar1[[3]]*ar2[[3]]) // NullifyMissing;
ar3[[3]] = 3*(ar1[[2]]*ar2[[1]] + ar1[[3]]*ar2[[2]] + ar1[[4]]*ar2[[3]]) // NullifyMissing;
ar3[[4]] = 2*(ar1[[3]]*ar2[[1]] + ar1[[4]]*ar2[[2]] + ar1[[5]]*ar2[[3]]) // NullifyMissing;
```

But I would suggest that you construct your table in more explicit way:

```
In[1]:= ar1 = {a1, a2, a3, a4};
        ar2 = {b1, b2, b3, b4};
        cf  = {2, 3, 3, 2};

In[4]:= Ar1[index_Integer] := Piecewise[{ar1[[index]], 0 < index <= Length[ar1]}];
        Ar1[index_Span] := Table[Ar1[i], {i, Range @@ index}];

In[6]:= ar3 = Table[cf[[i]] Ar1[i-1 ;; i+1].ar2[[1 ;; 3]], {i, 4}]

Out[6]= {2 (a1 b2 + a2 b3), 3 (a1 b1 + a2 b2 + a3 b3),
         3 (a2 b1 + a3 b2 + a4 b3), 2 (a3 b1 + a4 b2)}
```